# Parsing signatures with regex, having "fun" with array return values

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, signature

I have this [nasty] regex to capture a VBA procedure signature with all the parts in a bucket:

```
    public static string ProcedureSyntax
    {
        get
        {
            return
                @"(?:(?<accessibility>Friend|Private|Public)\s)?(?:(?<kind>Sub|Function|Property\s(Get|Let|Set)))\s(?<identifier>(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|(?:\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\]))\((?<parameters>.*)?\)(?:\sAs\s(?<reference>(((?<library>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*))\.)?(?<identifier>([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\]))(?<array>\((?<size>(([0-9]+)\,?\s?)*|([0-9]+\sTo\s[0-9]+\,?\s?)+)\))?)?";
        }
    }
```

Part of it is overkill and will match illegal array syntaxes (in the context of a procedure's signature), but that's not my concern right now.

The problem is that this part:

```
\((?<parameters>.*)?\)
```

breaks when a function (or property getter) returns an array, because then the signature will look something like this:

```vb
Public Function GetSomeArray() As Variant()
```

Or like this:

```vb
Public Function GetSomeArray(ByVal foo As Integer) As Variant()
```

And that makes the function's return type completely borked, because the `parameters` capture group will pick up this:

```
ByVal foo As Integer) As Variant(
```

I know *why* it's happening - because my regex is assuming the *last closing brace* is the one delimiting the `parameters` capture group.

Is there a way to fix my regex to change that, without impacting performance too much?

The catch is that this is a valid signature:

```vb
Public Function DoSomething(foo As Integer, ParamArray bar()) As Variant()
```

---

I have another separate regex to handle individual parameters, and it would work great... if this one didn't get confused with array return types.

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

What I need, is a `parameters` group that doesn't include the `) As Variant(` part, like it does when the return type isn't an array:

[image]

Comment: What's your expected output? How the groups would look like?

Comment: @AvinashRaj edited; please let me know if you need more details ;)

Comment: could you check this https://regex101.com/r/dM9pG7/1 ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj how... you're a wizard!!

Comment: You should refer to the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx if you want to do a full-feature parsing.

Comment: @nhahtdh yeah, but that's VB.NET - I *think* what I have works for VBA/VB6.

Comment: @retailcoder: If you can pass a expression with `()` as a default value to a parameter, then it is going to cause problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here you go....

```
(?:(?<accessibility>Friend|Private|Public)\s)?(?:(?<kind>Sub|Function|Property\s(Get|Let|Set)))\s(?<identifier>(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|(?:\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\]))\((?<parameters>(?:\(\)|[^()])*)?\)(?:\sAs\s(?<reference>(((?<library>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*))\.)?(?<identifier1>([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\]))(?<array>\((?<size>(([0-9]+)\,?\s?)*|([0-9]+\sTo\s[0-9]+\,?\s?)+)\))?)?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dM9pG7/1)

**What are the changes made in your original regex?**

I just changed this `\((?<parameters>.*)?\)` part in your original regex to `\((?<parameters>(?:\(\)|[^()])*)?\)` . That is, `.*` in your pattern will do a greedy match upto the last `)` symbol, but this `(?:\(\)|[^()])*` matches `()` part or any character not of `(` or `)` zero or more times. so this matches the strings like `foo` or `foo()bar` ..

Comment: @retailcoder use this https://regex101.com/r/dM9pG7/2 if necessary. You're always welcome :)

Comment: @retailcoder we need to add another special thanks. =;)-